# Get an Extension Attribute from AD?

Tags: c#, active-directory

I got this from a member of our Network Team:

[image]

You can see that extensionAttribute2 has a value in it.  How can I retrieve this value - I cannot see extensionAttributes anywere in UserPrincipal object - unless I am missing something.

I have went back a level further and tried the below:

```
        UserPrincipal myUser = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(con, identityName);

        DirectoryEntry de = (myUser.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry);

        if (de != null)
        {
            // go for those attributes and do what you need to do
            if (de.Properties.Contains("extensionAttribute2"))
            {
                return de.Properties["extensionAttribute2"][0].ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }
        }
```

However this does not work - debugging this there are about 40 properties available but none for extensionAttribute2

Answer (score 6):

If you're on .NET 3.5 and up and using the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` (S.DS.AM) namespace, you can easily extend the existing `UserPrincipal` class to get at more advanced properties, like `Manager` etc.

Read all about it here:

- [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx)
- [MSDN docs on System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx)

Basically, you just define a derived class based on `UserPrincipal`, and then you define your additional properties you want:

```
[DirectoryRdnPrefix("CN")]
[DirectoryObjectClass("Person")]
public class UserPrincipalEx : UserPrincipal
{
    // Inplement the constructor using the base class constructor. 
    public UserPrincipalEx(PrincipalContext context) : base(context)
    { }

    // Implement the constructor with initialization parameters.    
    public UserPrincipalEx(PrincipalContext context,
                         string samAccountName,
                         string password,
                         bool enabled) : base(context, samAccountName, password, enabled)
    {} 

    // Create the "extensionAttribute2" property.    
    [DirectoryProperty("extensionAttribute2")]
    public string ExtensionAttribute2
    {
        get
        {
            if (ExtensionGet("extensionAttribute2").Length != 1)
                return string.Empty;

            return (string)ExtensionGet("extensionAttribute2")[0];
        }
        set { ExtensionSet("extensionAttribute2", value); }
    }
}
```

Now, you can use the "extended" version of the `UserPrincipalEx` in your code:

```
using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{
    // Search the directory for the new object. 
    UserPrincipalEx inetPerson = UserPrincipalEx.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.SamAccountName, "someuser");

    // you can easily access the ExtensionAttribute2 now
    string department = inetPerson.ExtensionAttribute2;
}
```

Comment: So I have this - using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement; in my class where im trying to use the UserPrincipalEx - however where I use UserPrincipalEx.FindByIdentity(ctx, identityName); I get a cannot implicitly convert AccountManagement.UserPrincipal to MyProj.Web.UserPrincipalEx - an explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: I cant' get this to work either. There's a missing step or a syntax error in this code. You can't cast from UserPrincipal to UserPrincipalEx and you can't access the new property from the newly created userprinipal object.

Comment: The missing thing in this answer is that you also need to override the static method FindByIdentity within the class that extends UserPrincipal. See the example from MSDN: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaevans/2012/04/11/querying-active-directory-using-principal-extensions-in-system-directoryservices-accountmanagement/ -- you need to call FindByIdentityWithType to get it to do the type conversion for you.

Answer (score 4):

Using the code that marc_s used add the following:

```
        public static new UserPrincipalEx FindByIdentity(PrincipalContext context, string identityValue)
        {
            return (UserPrincipalEx)FindByIdentityWithType(context, typeof(UserPrincipalEx), identityValue);
        }

        // Implement the overloaded search method FindByIdentity. 
        public static new UserPrincipalEx FindByIdentity(PrincipalContext context, IdentityType identityType, string identityValue)
        {
            return (UserPrincipalEx)FindByIdentityWithType(context, typeof(UserPrincipalEx), identityType, identityValue);
        }
```