# System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement and returning an IEnumerable of Active Directory user

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, active-directory

I'm trying to query Active Directory and return an IEnumerable but with properties like Title and EmailAddress, which aren't shown doing PrincipalSearcher.Findll(). If I use PrincipalSearcher.FindOne(), it has much more properties (still not Title, though) so I'm trying to figure out what I'm doing differently or how to get the info I need out. I've worn out Google trying to find more info and it seems like UserPrincipal.GetUnderlyingObject() might be the ticket but I'm not understanding how to involve that into a foreach loop in order to populate it into the List.

```
    public class ADUser
    {
        public string SamAccountName { get; set; }
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<ADUser> Get(string username)
        {
            var users = new List<ADUser>();

            var principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "domain.com");
            var userPrincipal = new UserPrincipal(principalContext)
            {
                SamAccountName = username
            };

            var principalSearcher = new PrincipalSearcher(userPrincipal);

            foreach (var user in principalSearcher.FindAll())
            {
                users.Add(new ADUser
                {
                    SamAccountName = user.SamAccountName,
                    DisplayName = user.DisplayName,
                    //Title = user.Title //Won't work, no Title property
                });
            }

            return users;
        }
    }
```

This works but only returns a fraction of the properties .FindOne() does, but if I do FindOne(), I won't be able to search for partial usernames, such as "jsm" returning "John Smith" and "James Smoth".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get Active Directory Attributes not represented by the UserPrincipal class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3929561/how-to-get-active-directory-attributes-not-represented-by-the-userprincipal-clas)

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19492883/get-an-extension-attribute-from-ad

Comment: These are putting me in the right direction, but I'm still not able to get the Title property inside of the foreach loop. I can see it outside, by doing "userPrincipal.Title", but that isn't helping me if I can't put it into the List<ADUser> for later iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that you can do this:

```
        foreach (var user in principalSearcher.FindAll())
        {
            var userDe = (DirectoryEntry) user.GetUnderlyingObject();
            users.Add(new ADUser
            {
                SamAccountName = user.SamAccountName,
                DisplayName = user.DisplayName,
                Title = userDe.Properties["title"]?.Value.ToString()
            });
        }
```

This is part of the reason I never use the `AccountManagement` namespace anymore. It uses `DirectoryEntry` in the background and hides its complexity to make the basic things easier for you, but you still have to revert to using `DirectoryEntry` directly for some things. And it actually performs slower than using `DirectoryEntry`/`DirectorySearcher` directly.

Here's an example of how you can do the same thing via `DirectorySearcher`. It is a little more complicated, but I bet you'll find it performs faster:

```
public class ADUser
{
    public string SamAccountName { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ADUser> Get(string username)
    {
        var users = new List<ADUser>();

        var search = new DirectorySearcher(
            new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://domain.com"),
            $"(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(sAMAccountName={username}))",
            new [] { "sAMAccountName", "displayName", "title" } //The attributes you want to see
        ) {
            PageSize = 1000 //If you're expecting more than 1000 results, you need this otherwise you'll only get the first 1000 and it'll stop
        };

        using (var results = search.FindAll()) {
            foreach (SearchResult result in results)
            {
                users.Add(new ADUser
                {
                    SamAccountName = result.Properties.Contains("sAMAccountName") ? result.Properties["sAMAccountName"][0].ToString() : null,
                    DisplayName = result.Properties.Contains("displayName") ? result.Properties["displayName"][0].ToString() : null,
                    Title = result.Properties.Contains("title") ? result.Properties["title"][0].ToString() : null
                });
            }
        }
        return users;
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess you'll never expect more than 1000 results when you're searching by username :) It just threw me off since you're returning a list. It's a good thing to know anyway.

Comment: I'm getting an error: "ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index" when I try to run that code on both exact usernames as well as partial.. I'm thinking it may be related to the "new []" ?

Comment: I'm not getting any exception. Which line is throwing the exception for you?

Comment: If you want it to work for partial usernames too, you have to add a `*` to the filter: `$"(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(sAMAccountName={username}*))"`

Comment: Line 35 of ADUser.cs, the "users.Add( new ADUser" line.

Comment: I figured it out, I assumed the question mark in ["title"]?[0] meant it was able to be nullable, but I'm getting the error because one account has no Title field populated. How can I make it able to be null?

Comment: Right, sorry. You have to add a check using `.Properties.Contains()`. I've updated my code.

Comment: That's the kind of stuff the `AccountManagement` namespace protects you from :) but at a cost...

Comment: Thanks so much for the help, it's exactly what I needed. I've seriously been fighting trying to get this working all day.

Comment: No problem. I've been there! :)